# android: how to create ACRA crash Report Txt File?

Tags: android, acra

I want to Create Text File of Crash Logs Information by ACRA Crash Report Instead Of EMail/GoogleDoc etc. so how can i achieve this goal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can implement your own ReportSender that saves everything to file according official docs.
https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Report-Destinations#implementing-your-own-sender

Comment: The project is now on github, the current link is: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#implementing-your-own-sender

Comment: Thanks. Merged link into answer.